# Split document on 2 screens in word 2013

Tags: word-2013

I have small uncomfortable thing after installation of word 2013.
In elder versions (2007,2010) i could split view of document like on screen: http://i59.tinypic.com/dzgy80.png

In version 2013 small triangle, which split screen, located in right bottom corner. All i did earlier - click and drag down.
I tried to find this option in settings, but not found anything helpfull

How can i do it in word 2013? Is it possible?

Comment: It's in the view tab and it's called split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View -> Split
Not really StackOverflow question I guess.